# How should I run Unit Test from VisualStudio on an remote test agent on another computer

Tags: visual-studio, automated-tests

I have a server (in a work group ) running Test Controller and Test Agent both, from my visual studio my local pc I am able to connect to the test controller and restart test agent and test controller I added testsettings to my solution and selected my Test Controller as remote execution of the unit test, when I run the test from visual studio the console shows the test is starting and the Test Explorer shows the green progress but after few minutes nothing happens then 
"A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond" is shown in the test console

Also on the server side in the log file of TestController I get

4088, 13, 2014/12/29, 12:22:49.507, WINxxxx\QTController.exe, ControllerSpooledJob: creating spooled job for test run ....C 2014-12-29 13:22:41'

I, 4088, 13, 2014/12/29, 12:22:49.538, WINxxxx\QTController.exe, ControllerObject: Queuing TestRun b6925df9-4ffe-4a75-9193-579033a44409

but nothing more,Why I can not get the test result in my Visual Studio?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the client computer (running visual studio) should be in the same network to be able to communicate with Test Controller server(in our case it should have a valid IP).